# How to avoid going to the next page after display an error message in ADF?

Tags: java, action, actionlistener, oracle-adf

I have a question.I need to check an email from View Object.If email not exist, i will perform some code.If email already exist, it will display some message that email already exist.

Currently I already do this,message "this email already use" will throw if email is exist.
But my problem is, user still can go to the next page if this message have been throw. So how to block user from go to the next page if got this message.

Here I attach some code:

```
   public void saveAdditionalProfile(ActionEvent event) { {
    //        saveAndExit()
    try {

        int rowCount = 0;
        ViewObject emailVO1 = appModule.getIwteEmployeeVO1();
        currentRow = emailVO1.getCurrentRow();
        String strEmail1 = (String)currentRow.getAttribute("Email1");
        String SSN = (String)currentRow.getAttribute("Ssn");
        rowCount = getEmpCountByEmail(strEmail1, SSN);


        if(rowCount == 0){
       //have another method here


        }
        else{
            Util.displayErrorMessage("Email has been used.");   
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: Add catch code
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
public static int getEmpCountByEmail(String email, String SSN) {
    AppModuleImpl appModule = Util.getAppmodule("AppModuleDataControl");        
    ViewObjectImpl emailVO = appModule.getIwteEmployeeVO1();
    emailVO.setWhereClause("UPPER(Email1) = '" + email.toUpperCase() + "' AND SSN <> '"+ SSN + "'");
    emailVO.executeQuery();
    emailVO.setWhereClause("");

    return emailVO.getRowCount();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How do you navigate to the next page?
How is the upper method invoked?

If the upper method is invoke for navigation to the next page, it's easy.

```
 else{
      Util.displayErrorMessage("Email has been used.");   
      break;
     }
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Hi...thanks for the reply.I have button that will do the action.I put some action at the button that submit the data to the next page.
For example:  
`button save and next    
 action listener:#{pageFlowScope.profileBean.saveAdditionalProfile}
 action: summary(action to the next page call summary).
 Action listener will call the method that i show above.Can i use 'break' to avoid it?